# Maximum Lat and Long bounds for the world - Google Maps API LatLngBounds()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

The Google Maps terrain view by default has unlimited panning of the map tile. You can use `LatLngBounds()` to limit this, but what are the maximum and minimum coordinates I should use to set the viewport as just the earth and not outside the map region?

Coordinates for North America:

```
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90)
);
```

I've tried `(+90, -180)(-90,180)` to no luck.

Comment: On a mercator projection, latitude goes up to 85 and -85, not 90.

Comment: The Mercator projection is not limited to latitudes from 85° to -85°. It just becomes increasingly distorted at extreme latitudes, and Google Maps cuts the projection off at around those latitudes.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The links provided by @Marcelo & @Doc are *good* for understanding the *derivation* of the Lat Lng:

- http://www.cienciaviva.pt/latlong/anterior/gps.asp?accao=changelang&lang=en
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/google-maps-api/oJkyualxzyY/pNv1SE7qpBoJ
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Mathematics_of_the_Mercator_projection

But if you *just* want an answer for the *maximum bounds* for **Google Maps**:

`Latitude: -85 to +85`  (*actually -85.05115 for some reason*)

`Longitude: -180 to +180`

*Try* it for yourself on the Google Maps:

- https://maps.google.com/?q=85,180
- https://maps.google.com/?q=-85.05115,180

(You may need to *Zoom Out*. See how the pin is at the "edge" of the world - these are the *limits*)

So in your code *Try*:

```
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),           // top left corner of map
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180)            // bottom right corner
);
```

*Please edit this wiki (or update your question) once you have the answer. Thanks*

Comment: Thanks. I had to use the following for java:     private static final LatLngBounds EARTH = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-84.9, -180),           // top left corner of map
            new LatLng(84.9, 180)            // bottom right corner
    );

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBounds
LatLngBounds are SW corner (-85, -180) to NE corner (+85, +180), rather than top-left to bottom-right in the answer.

Comment: Tried this in polyline tool but does not seem te give the enitre area, this is a very common issue. It is however the biggest and smallest possible longitude and latitude value. https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/?coordinates=85.0000000%2C%20185.0000000%0A-85.0000000%2C%20185.0000000%0A-85.0000000%2C%20-185.0000000%0A85.0000000%2C%20-185.0000000%0A85.0000000%2C%20185.0000000

Answer (score 12):

See [**this post**](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/msg/1aa4ea4e48f5dba4?hl=en) in the old Google Groups, which describes the math of the projection.

Quote:

> the map doesn't start at 85 degrees, but rather the degree that
> makes the map square.  This is can be simply calaculated as:
> atan(sinh(PI)) *180 / PI = 85.05112878....

Note that the tile calculation in that post is for the old API V2, but the projection should be the same.

Comment: All I'm looking for is tested, working maximum minimum coordinates?

Comment: Then read the post, understand it and test the coordinates. I'm not going to do your homework for you, kiddo.

Answer (score 11):

You may do the following to get the Max Lat and Long bounds of the world with the help of Google Maps :

**1:** Set the Zoom Level 1 of Google Maps While setting up the Google Map Stuff :

```
mapOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
 .....
}
```

**2.**     Do the following to get NorthEast and SouthWest Bound of this Map :

> map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
>   mapOptions);
>
> ```
>      // NorthEast Latitude : 89.45016124669523
>      var latNEValue =  map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
>     // NorthEast Longitude : 180
>      var longNEValue = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
>      // SouthWest Latitude : -87.71179927260242
>      var latSWValue =  map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
>      // Southwest Latitude :  -180
>      var longSWValue = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
> ```

**3.** It will give you following NorthEast and SouthWest Bounds :

> NorthEast Latitude : 89.45016124669523
>
> NorthEast Longitude : 180
>
> SouthWest Latitude : -87.71179927260242
>
> Southwest Longitude :  -180

Similarly on Zoom Level- 0 , It give following points :

> NorthEast Latitude : 89.99346179538875
>
> NorthEast Longitude : 180
>
> SouthWest Latitude : -89.98155760646617
>
> Southwest Longitude :  -180

Above trick helped me to solve my business problem which required max lat/long.

Answer (score 4):

for more details in GPS values you can read [this](http://www.cienciaviva.pt/latlong/anterior/gps.asp?accao=changelang&lang=en) article.

Article explain that :

- Latitude is the distance from the Equator measured along the Greenwich Meridian. This distance is measured in degrees and ranges between 0º to 90º North and South.
- Longitude is the distance from the Greenwich Meridian measured along the Equator. This distance is measured in degrees and ranges from 0º to 180º East and West.

Comment: So in the short, sample max and min coordinates for NW point and SW?

Comment: It's strange, when you look [the official google map API doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#LatLng) it's really between 90/-90 for lattitude and 180/-180 for longitude, in your latlong declaration, you don't reverse latitude and longitude?

Comment: Nope, my code works fine for the US demographic latlng bounds.