# google map showing wrong map when decimal latitude and longitude is provided from mysql

Tags: javascript, php

I noticed that google maps does not show the correct map, when  values from a mysql database having field type decimel or float are provided. varchar is accepted.

source the the browser show the correct lat and long values and no blank spaces or other issues. what ever i tried Decimal does  not sohw the correct map

```
           $lat= $row['latitude']; (decimel from mysql, does not work)
        $long=$row['longitude'];



    $lat=15.624256;(works)
    $long=73.7943410;


   <script>
   function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$long; ?>),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Could we please have a look at your database schema? with correct datatypes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data. Also put enough validations to ensure you have sane coordinates and proper precision. The query should replace null with 0.

In the resulting html page, check if the html and javascript are properly formatted with the data.

Write a dummy php to know the data

```
$lat= $row['latitude'];
$long=$row['longitude'];
echo '<p>'.$lat.','.$long.'</p>'
```

TIP: Preferably avoid $long variable name. Use $longitude instead

Comment: CREATE TABLE `branches` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `googlelink` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `delete_data` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `delete_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `mylongitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `mylatitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

Comment: i have added both decimel and varchar for testing... still wont work after changing $loang to $longitude

Comment: changing variable name is only a "good practice"... But my suggestion is to put column constraints in DB. Check this for valid values http://stackoverflow.com/a/13824556/1791209