# Google Maps Limit the Bounds to one instance of the world

Tags: javascript, maps

I am trying to limit the scrolling of a google map to one instance of the world as in all directions.  However I'm finding that my map center is NEVER contained within my strict bounds which from what I've read is the bounds for one "world".  Anyone know why my map center is never contained within my map?

EDIT: I would expect the center of the map to be valid anywhere within the strictBounds...i.e the single instance of the world (i.e you can't scroll left right up or down to see the north americas twice) My gut tells me that if its not contained within my coordinates that the coordinates are wrong, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849636/maximum-lat-and-long-bounds-for-the-world-google-maps-api-latlngbounds) stack overflow post tells me otherwise.

```
// Bounds for world
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),           // top left corner of map
      new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180)           // bottom right corner
);

var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

// Listen for the dragend event
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
  console.log("dragend");
    if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

    // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds
    var c = map.getCenter(),
    x = c.lng(),
    y = c.lat(),
    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

    if (x < minX) x = minX;
    if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
    if (y < minY) y = minY;
    if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

    console.log(x,y);

    // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate any further? Maybe explain what you expect to happen in a typical use case as opposed to what is currently going wrong?

Comment: just updated with more info

Answer (score 1):

I see the following changes that need to be made:

> 1. Your maxY and minY values were mixed up:

```
maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
minY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
maxY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
```

> 2. If any of the current coordinates are outside of the strict bound coordinates then we want to pan to the last valid center:

```
if (x < minX || x > maxX || y < minY || y > maxY) 
    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
```

> 3. Depending on the type of functionality you want, update the value of `lastValidCenter`:

```
if (x < minX || x > maxX || y < minY || y > maxY) 
    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
else
    lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
```

> 4. Just my opinion but I'd use a different event, rather than `dragend` maybe something more immediate like `center_changed`. But this again depends on your desired functionality.