# Google Maps API: Not showing a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing some integration of my mini web apps with a Google Map. The problem is that

```
...
marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition({lat:10,lng:10});
marker.setMap(map);
...
```

like this map shows the marker, but when I do like that

```
...
marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition({lat:176.6249978542328,lng:67.5018425707725});
marker.setMap(map);
...
```

or...

```
...
marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition({lat:176,lng:67});
marker.setMap(map);
...
```

it doesn't show any marker.

P.S. I've checked everything... Map is working, with `{lat:10,lng:10}` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values for latitude and longitude in Google Maps

**Latitude**: -85 to +85  (actually -85.05115)

**Longitude**: -180 to +180

Comment: isnt latitude -90 to +90?

Comment: Im just curious whats the difference? According to this page:
[Google Maps Help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en)

`Check that the first number in your latitude coordinate is between -90 and 90 and the first number in your longitude coordinate is between -180 and 180.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849636/maximum-lat-and-long-bounds-for-the-world-google-maps-api-latlngbounds#answer-11868731

Answer (score 1):

your longitude is ok. But latitude is wrong. cannot more than 85 and less than -85