# How to add polygon properly in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

When using leaflet.js to render polygon.
The following examples have different results.

#### Example 1

```
const map = L.map('map', {
    preferCanvas: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false
});
const latlngs = [
    [
        6,
        5
    ],
    [
        7,
        1
    ],
    [
        9,
        2
    ]
];
const polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
```

[image]

---

#### Example 2

```
    ...
    const latlngs = [
        [
            116,
            115
        ],
        [
            117,
            111
        ],
        [
            119,
            112
        ]
    ];
    const polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
```

[image]

#### Why is that?

#### And what can I do if I have to set latlngs data like Example 2.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that Leaflet uses latitude and longitude by default and projects it on a plane using a Web Mercator projection. On your second polygon, the coordinates are [out of bounds for latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849636/maximum-lat-and-long-bounds-for-the-world-google-maps-api-latlngbounds#13824556).

If you just need to draw a triangle in "pixel" coordinates, you can use [CRS.Simple](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).

```
const map = L.map('map', {
    preferCanvas: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    attributionControl: false,
    // Add this line:
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekqvwo76/