# How to generate random geocoordinates using random module

Tags: python, random, latitude-longitude

How to generate random latitude and longitude using Python 3 `random` module? I already googled and read documentation and not found a way to do this.

Comment: Generate a latitude then generate a longitude? There's nothing special to it, AFAIK, they're just floats between -90 and +90, or -180 and +180.

Comment: Depending on the distribution you want, you probably won't want to pick a latitude uniformly at random - you'll get a disproportionate number of results near the poles that way.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem when using uniform distributions for *both* the latitude and the longitude
is that physically, the latitude is NOT uniformly distributed.

So if you plan to use these random points for something like some statiscal averaging computation,
or a physics Monte-Carlo simulation, the results will risk being incorrect.

And if you plot a graphical representation of the “uniform”  random points, they will seem to cluster in the polar regions.

To picture that, consider on planet Earth the zone that lies between 89 and 90 degrees of latitude (North).
The length of a degree of latitude is 10,000/90 = 111 km. That zone is a circle of radius 111 km,
centered around the North Pole. Its area is about 3.14 * 111 * 111 ≈ 39,000 km<sup>2</sup>

On the other hand, consider the zone that lies between 0 and 1 degree of latitude.
This is a strip whose length is 40,000 km (the Equator) and whose width is 111 km,
so its area is 4.44 millions km<sup>2</sup>. Much larger than the polar zone.

### A simple algorithm:

A possibility is to use Gaussian-distributed random variables, as provided by the Python library.
If we build a 3D vector whose 3 components have Gaussian distributions, the overall
probability distribution is like
exp(-x<sup>2</sup>) * exp(-y<sup>2</sup>) * exp(-z<sup>2</sup>)
but this is the same thing as exp(-(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>))
or exp(-r<sup>2</sup>), where r is the distance from the origin.

So these vectors have no privileged direction. Once normalized to unit length, they are *uniformly*
distributed on the unit sphere. They solve our problem with the latitude distribution.

The idea is implemented by the following Python code:

```
import  math
import  random

def randlatlon1():
    pi = math.pi
    cf = 180.0 / pi  # radians to degrees Correction Factor

    # get a random Gaussian 3D vector:
    gx = random.gauss(0.0, 1.0)
    gy = random.gauss(0.0, 1.0)
    gz = random.gauss(0.0, 1.0)

    # normalize to an equidistributed (x,y,z) point on the unit sphere:
    norm2 = gx*gx + gy*gy + gz*gz
    norm1 = 1.0 / math.sqrt(norm2)
    x = gx * norm1
    y = gy * norm1
    z = gz * norm1

    radLat = math.asin(z)      # latitude  in radians
    radLon = math.atan2(y,x)   # longitude in radians

    return (round(cf*radLat, 5), round(cf*radLon, 5))
```

### A sanity check:

Euclidean geometry provides a formula for the probability of a spherical zone
defined by minimal/maximal latitude and longitude. The corresponding Python code is like this:

```
def computeProbaG(minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon):
    pi  = math.pi
    rcf = pi / 180.0  # degrees to radians Correction Factor
    lonProba = (maxLon - minLon) / 360.0
    minLatR  = rcf * minLat
    maxLatR  = rcf * maxLat
    latProba = (1.0/2.0) * (math.sin(maxLatR) - math.sin(minLatR))
    return (lonProba * latProba)
```

And we can also compute an approximation of that same probability by random sampling, using
the random points provided by a function such as `randlatlon1`, and counting what
percentage of them happen to fall within the selected zone:

```
def computeProbaR(randlatlon, ranCount, minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon):
    norm  = 1.0 / ranCount
    pairs = [randlatlon()  for i in range(ranCount)]
    acceptor = lambda p: ( (p[0] > minLat)  and  (p[0] < maxLat)     and
                           (p[1] > minLon)  and   (p[1] < maxLon) )
    selCount = sum(1 for p in filter(acceptor, pairs))
    return (norm * selCount)
```

Equipped with these two functions, we can check for various geometric parameter sets
that the geometric and probabilistic results are in good agreement, with `ranCount` set to one million random points:

```
ranCount = 1000*1000
print (" ")
probaG1 = computeProbaG(                       30, 60, 45, 90)
probaR1 = computeProbaR(randlatlon1, ranCount, 30, 60, 45, 90)
print ("probaG1 = %f" % probaG1)
print ("probaR1 = %f" % probaR1)
print (" ")
probaG2 = computeProbaG(                        10, 55, -40, 160)
probaR2 = computeProbaR(randlatlon1, ranCount,  10, 55, -40, 160)
print ("probaG2 = %f" % probaG2)
print ("probaR2 = %f" % probaR2)
print (" ")
```

### Execution output:

```
$ python3 georandom.py

probaG1 = 0.022877
probaR1 = 0.022852
 
probaG2 = 0.179307
probaR2 = 0.179644

$
```

So the two sort of numbers appears to agree reasonably here.

### Addendum:

For the sake of completeness, we can add a second **algorithm** which is less intuitive but derives from a wider statistical principle.

To solve the problem of the latitude distribution, we can use the [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) theorem. In order to do so, we need some formula for the probability of the latitude to be less than an arbitrary prescribed value, φ.

The region of the unit 3D sphere whose latitude is less than a given φ is known as a *spherical cap*. Its area can be obtained thru elementary calculus, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) for example.

The spherical cap area is given by formula: A = 2π * (1 + sin(φ))
The corresponding probability can be obtained by dividing this area by the overall area of the unit 3D sphere, that is 4π, corresponding to φ = φ<sub>max</sub> = π/2. Hence:

p = Proba{latitude < φ} = (1/2) * (1 + sin(φ))

Or, conversely:

φ = arcsin (2*p - 1)

From the *Inverse Transform Sampling* theorem, a fair sampling of the latitude (in radians) is obtained by replacing the probability p by a random variable uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. In Python, this gives:

```
lat = math.asin(2*random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) - 1.0)
```

As for the longitude, this is an independent random variable that is still uniformly distributed between -π and +π (in radians). So the overall Python sampler code is:

```
def randlatlon2r():
    pi = math.pi
    cf = 180.0 / pi  # radians to degrees Correction Factor
    u0 = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    u1 = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    radLat = math.asin(2*u0 - 1.0)  # angle with Equator   - from +pi/2 to -pi/2
    radLon = (2*u1 - 1) * pi        # longitude in radians - from -pi to +pi 
    return (round(radLat*cf,5), round(radLon*cf,5))
```

This code has been found to pass successfully the sanity check as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a [random number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824556/1059860) between

`Latitude: -85 to +85 (actually -85.05115 for some reason)`

`Longitude: -180 to +180`

Comment: That assumes you want to map them onto google maps (or some other mercator projection I guess), the actual bounds of latitude are -90 and +90.

Comment: @Masklinn no, I checked, it is -85 to +85

Comment: Latitudes go from -90° to 90°. Google Maps cuts the map off at around -85° and 85°, but that's just because the Mercator projection gets increasingly distorted at extreme latitudes. It has nothing to do with how latitudes or geography work.

Comment: What Masklinn said is correct, if you intend to use determine a location on anything else other than Mercator projection, probably you should use -90 to +90.

Answer (score 0):

As @tandem wrote in his answer, the range for latitude is almost `-90 to +90` (it is cut on maps) and for longitude it is `-180 to +180`. To generate random float numbers in this range use `random.uniform` function:

```
import random

# returns (lat, lon)
def randlatlon():
    return (round(random.uniform( -90,  90), 5),
            round(random.uniform(-180, 180), 5))
```

It is rounded to 5 digits after comma because that extra accuracy is unnecessary.